# How to move a graphic object in a window at a certain cursor position?

Tags: java, javafx

[Visual addition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtuzE.png)

I read that when creating a window a main cycle is started which runs all the events. From this it follows that it is impossible to make a cycle for changing the position of graphic objects in a window. This is not accurate, but somehow it works. In an abstract way, I understood it all.: DDDDD

```
scene.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
            System.out.println(e.getX()+" "+e.getY());

        if(e.getX()>750)
        {
          camera.cameraControlX(-0.5);
        }else if(e.getX()<50)
        {
          camera.cameraControlX(0.5);
        }
        if(e.getY()>550)
        {
          camera.cameraControlY(-0.5);
        }else if(e.getY()<50)
        {
          camera.cameraControlY(0.5);
        }
```

In addition to the picture, I wrote this code. As the mouse moves, everything works as it should. However, I would like to achieve the movement of the house as long as the mouse is in the corner of the windows. Please tell me how to do this? Sorry for my english.

Comment: I've no idea what `cameraControlY` and `cameraControlX` does but there are animations that allow you to run code regularly on the JavaFX application thread and if you save the coordinates from the `onMouseMoved` event, you should be able to get the results you're trying to achieve. I don't get which result you're trying to achieve though.

Comment: These functions are a wrapper for moving the picture normally.

Comment: protected void objectControlX(double x){
  imageview.setX(imageview.getX()+x);
  }
  protected void objectControlY(double x){
  imageview.setY(imageview.getY()+x);
  }
  protected void objectControlXY(double x, double y){
  imageview.setX(imageview.getX()+x);
  imageview.setY(imageview.getY()+y);
  }

Comment: do you think i should use timeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your problem correctly, i think you want to have the camera continue moving as long as the curser is at one position. I have added an AnimationTimer which continues moving the camera as long as the curser stays in one position. here is my code

```
boolean north = false, east = false, south = false, west = false;

    scene.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
        if(e.getX()>750)
        {
            east = true;
        }else if(e.getX()<50)
        {
            west = true;
        }else{
            east = false;
            west = false;
        }
        if(e.getY()>550)
        {
            south = true;
        }else if(e.getY()<50)
        {
            north = true;
        }else{
            north = false;
            south = false;
        }
    });
    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            if(east)camera.cameraControlX(-0.5);
            if(west)camera.cameraControlX(0.5);
            if(south)camera.cameraControlY(-0.5);
            if(north)camera.cameraControlY(0.5);
        }
    };
    timer.start();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed!

Comment: I have postponed the resolution of this issue so far, so in the comments there is such a time lag. At first glance, the logic is appropriate, but in fact - in lambda expressions should be the final variables. I understand that the solution to this problem is the use of objects, for the final are links, not properties. What do you think?